# Integer double pointer in function parameter

Tags: c, function, pointers

What I've learned so far about pointers is:
a pointer refers to the address of a variable

```
int a = 0 ;
int *p = &a ;
```

and a double pointer refers to the address of a pointer variable

```
int *b = &a ;
int **c = &b ;
```

and as far as what I know is correct, I should have no problem in executing the codes below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void reference(int **input)
{
    **input = 963;
}

int main(void)
{
    int* value;

    reference(&value);

    printf("%d\n", *value);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, I expected to see "963" in console.
When I execute the code, build succeeds but cmd just stops.
What could be a possible problem for this simple code?

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  The main reason is that the function: `system()` is found in the header file: `stdlib.h` but the code is missing the necessary include statement.

Comment: regarding: `system("PAUSE");`  this is not portable.  It will fail when run under other than the windows OS.  Suggest  `int ch;  while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' );  getchar();`

Answer (score 4):

We can rewrite

```
int* value;
reference(&value);
```

without the function, giving

```
int* value;
int **input = &value;
**input = 963;
```

Because `*input` is `value`, the whole thing is equivalent to

```
int* value;
*value = 963;
```

This is wrong because `value` is uninitialized. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer has undefined behavior.

Fix:

```
int x;
int *value = &x;
reference(&value);
```

I.e. make `value` point somewhere were `963` can be stored.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `value` is a pointer that doesn't point to anything, it's dangling. You need to set it first.

```
int foo;
int* value;
value = &foo;
```

And now it works without crashing. You need to have a place for your data, either ont he stack (local variables) or on the heap (allocated with `malloc`).